# Performing T-test on subset of values in a Google Sheets range

Tags: google-spreadsheets, statistics

I have [a set of sports scores](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GQQTXKYQp4LvfGT__3rwLRRVrKwujUnMBaSVmf9kvHM/edit?usp=sharing) in Google Sheets. I have various subsets of scores for which I calculate the averages and standard deviations. I want to perform T-tests to determine if a particular subset is a statistically significant deviation from the overall, but I don't know how to select a subset of the range for the [T-Test function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055837?hl=en). I imagine it might have something to do with [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en-GB), but I haven't been able to figure out the correct combination of function nesting to get there, or how to perform a T-test using different numbers of data points.

[image: screenshot of the Google Sheet linked above, showing that each game has a team name, slot, and game number, with averages and standard deviations for the unique values in each]

Both the formulae `=TTEST($D$2:$D$25,ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A$2:$A$25=F8,$D$2:$D$25,"")),2,1)` and `=ARRAYFORMULA(TTEST($D$2:$D$25,IF($A$2:$A$25=F9,$D$2:$D$25,""),2,1))` show N/A, indicating that it is an error for the two ranges to be different sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### TTEST Type

In your `TTEST` formulas you are specifying a `type` of `1` which is a 'Paired Test'.  The 'Paired Test' requires an equal number of data points to be compared.  If you change the `type` to either of `2` or `3` you would no longer get the array mismatch `#N/A` error.

| Type | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | paired test |
| 2 | two-sample equal variance (homoscedastic) test |
| 3 | two-sample unequal variance (heteroscedastic) test |

##### Formula

`=TTEST(range1, range2, tails, type)`

1. **One Team's Results vs. All Teams'**
   This seemed to be what you were attempting in your formula

```
=TTEST(FILTER(score, team=F8),
       score,
       2, 2)

#  If excluding individual team from all 
#  teams' results then amend as follows

=TTEST(FILTER(score, team=F8),
       FILTER(score, team<>F8),
       2, 2)
```

2. **Games 1-3 vs. Average Games 1-3**
   <sup>*Uses array of `AVERAGE` Games 1, `AVERAGE` Games 2, & `AVERAGE` Games 3.*</sup>

```
=TTEST(FILTER(score,team=F8), 
       { AVERAGE(FILTER(score, game=1)),
         AVERAGE(FILTER(score, game=2)),
         AVERAGE(FILTER(score, game=3)) },
       2,2)

#  If excluding individual team from all 
#  teams' results then amend as follows

=TTEST(FILTER(score, team=F8), 
       { AVERAGE(FILTER(score, game=1, team<>F8)),
         AVERAGE(FILTER(score, game=2, team<>F8)), 
         AVERAGE(FILTER(score, game=3, team<>F8)) },
       2,2)
```

| Name | Range |
| --- | --- |
| game | TTEST!C2:C25 |
| score | TTEST!D2:D25 |
| team | TTEST!A2:A25 |

Comment: Thank you (and thank you for introducing me to the `FILTER` function).